# File remains open after process killed

Tags: c#, file-io, process

My code, with some non-essential bits stripped out, looks like:

```
using (Process p = new Process()()
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = batfile;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"""" + filename + @"""";
    p.Start();
    if (!p.WaitForExit(timeout))
    {
        p.Kill();
        if (!p.WaitForExit(timeout))
        {
            return failure;
        }
    }
}
File.Delete(filename);

return success;
```

So, I create a process to execute a .bat file, pass the .bat file a filename to process, then start the process, wait for it to terminate, then delete the file it just processed.  Normally, this works just fine.

Sometimes though, what's going on in the .bat file hangs, and I have to kill the process to recover.  When that happens, the File.Delete() throws an exception "The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process".

Thinking that maybe I just needed to wait a bit I put a Thread.Sleep() for several second before the File.Delete() - I have increased the sleep time to 30 seconds and I'm still seeing the exception.  Surely the open handle doesn't hang around that long after a process has died?

How do I either fix or workaround this?

Comment: Process has an [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event, have you tried deleting the file within this?

Comment: Yes - I added "if (p.HasExited)" and tried deleting in that - same result.  But I shouldn't need that - the WaitForExit() returned true, so it must have exited.  

Edit - sorry, misread your comment, and thought you meant the HasExited property.  Haven't looked at an Exited event.

Comment: You killed cmd.exe, the command processor that interprets the .bat file.  You did not kill the program that was started by the command in the .bat file.  So this is entirely normal.

Comment: I strongly suspect some other process will have the file handle open, no the process which has terminated just now, I suggest you to find which process is locking the file. There are tools available for that.

Comment: No other process has the file open - I know that to be true.

Comment: @Hans Passant If cmd.exe dies, doesn't its children die too - including the .bat file?  If not, can I find the .bat pid without looking through all processes?

Comment: take a look the file with something like this: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/